# Can I use Oracle APEX's Db in .NET application?

Tags: .net, database, oracle, oracle-apex

I am working on a project these days in which I have to create a client side application along with an admin panel. In that project, I want to create the admin panel (which mostly needs reporting and the data stuff) using a low-code application development technique. In this case, I searched, and came to know about oracle Apex and Microsoft Power Apps between these I found Apex more suitable.
Now, in my case I have to use the same DB for both of the applications. So, my question is, if can we use the same DB in APEX and a .NET application? If so then, what would be the approach? And whether it would be cost effective or not? Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Yes, you can use .Net with an Oracle DB. APEX only works with Oracle DB. Depending on your needs, Oracle Express Edition is free, and there is a free tier for their Autonomous Transaction Processing database in the Oracle Cloud. Both include APEX.